# Find and replace surounding of a string in file

Tags: bash, vim

There are many occurrences of the following command in a Latex file:

```
\en{some_string}
```

This is a custom command for entering English text.
Now I want in each of these commands to delete the surroundings so that:

```
\en{some_string} ---> some_string.
```

How can I implement it using a bash or vim command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed` command as following:

```
sed --in-place=.bak 's/\\en{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g' your_file
```

This creates backup of your original file under .bak extension. Then it replaces all the the occurences in the file specified.

- `s/original/replace/g` replaces all occurences of `original` with `replace`
- `\(...\)` captures the match between to `\1` which is applied on the right side
- `[^}]*` matches any number of characters other than `}`
- `\\en{\([^}]*\)}` i.e. the full left hand side therefore matches the `\en{some_string}` pattern and stores what's between `{` and `}` to
- `\1` which is used as a replacement on the right hand side.

You can apply the exact same command also in `vim`:

```
vim your_file
:%s/\\en{\([^}]*\)}/\1/g
```

Here `:` switches to command line mode, `%` means a range of all lines of the file, the rest is the same.

Comment: The vim Command did the job but the --in-place parameter wasn't recognised by bash. Maybe the sed version of MacOs which I am using is the problem. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @buttercookie OS X uses a set of userland utilities based on FreeBSD. For that version of [`sed`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) you probably need to use the `-I .bak` flag. Use empty qoutes (`""`) with `-I` if you don't want backup files.

Answer (score 0):

vim regex to substitute all the lines in a file:

```
:%s/^\\en{\([0-9a-zA-Z_]*\)}/\1/
```